# How do I go about changing the contents of a page based on the URL? Express.js, Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, request

Okay. I know this question was a bit confusing, so let me decompose my question a bit further. For example, let's say I have the URL: https://example.com. I have an open GET endpoint at: https://example.com/user/* that will return a specific user's information based on what the contents of the "*" is. Lets say a specific user is at: https://example.com/user/12345. On an HTML page, I would like to put that user's profile contents and some of their hobbies. Again, this is theoretical. I have explored various solutions such as Handlebars.js which can dynamically change values based on the server request. However, this solution does not always work. Take a search engine for example at: https://mysearchengine.com/search?query=dogs. Here, we have a search query for dogs. How do I render all of the results to a HTML document without using a dynamic content module like Handlebars?

This question was particularly difficult to ask, so please do not mark this as "not enough information". I would be more than happy to clarify any questions you may have about the nature of my query. Thank you so much in advance,

Flight Dude.

Comment: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/render-dynamic-content-in-nodejs-using-templates-a58cae681148

Comment: Woah. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks for the swift response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to let y'all know I found my answer: EJS. Thanks!